# I cannot figure out why my code is returning an empty list

Tags: python, list

My code to the question "Write a function remove_duplicates that takes in a list and removes elements of the list that are the same (in the form of a new list)" returns an empty list, that is, `[]`, instead of a list with no duplicates. 
I cannot seem to understand why?

```
def remove_duplicates(sequence):
    k = []
    for x in sequence:
        for i in k:
            if x != i:
                k.append(x)
            else:
                k = k
    return k
```

Comment: `def remove_duplicates(sequence): return list(set(sequence))`

Comment: `for i in k` will do nothing for the first `x` since `k` is empty. So `k` is empty for the second `x`, etc. In the end, `k` stays empty until you exhaust the `sequence`.